# Remove portion from URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My site is having following url

**domain.com/ldr1/site/index/category/fashion**

and I want like

**domain.com/ldr1/fashion**

there should be no changes in the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^ldr1/site/index/category/(.*)$ /ldr1/$1 [L,R]
```

That will make the URL look like `domain.com/ldr1/fashion`.

Now, whether or not the resource at `/ldr1/fashion` exists or not is an entirely different issue.